# How to sort a dataframe based on multi-column and drop rows that do not sort

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, sorting

For example, if I had a dataframe that looks like

| A | B |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 8 |
| 4 | 9 |
| 2 | 5 |
| 6 | 2 |

Is there a easier way to sort the two rows where Col-A is in ascending order and B in descending order and any row that B cannot be ordered in descending be dropped? The second row should be dropped because 9 is greater than 5.

I am expecting a table that looks like

| A | B |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 8 |
| 2 | 5 |
| 6 | 2 |

Comment: Can you provide a larger example? The currently accepted solution seems inefficient for large datasets

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can [`sort_values`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html), then compute a [`cummin`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.cummin.html), drop the rows that violate the `cummin`:

```
tmp = df.sort_values(['A','B'], ascending=[True, False])

m = tmp['B'].le(tmp['B'].cummin())

out = tmp[m]

# or to keep the original DataFrame
out = df.loc[m[m].index]
```

Output:

```
   A  B
0  1  8
2  2  5
3  6  2
```

Comment: This works great too! Thanks!

Comment: yop, this is better solution